# In Neo4j how can I create a trigger?

Tags: java, neo4j

I would like to call some Java code when a node of a certain type is added, updated or deleted in Neo4j. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into using [TransactionEventHandler](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-examples/1.3/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html). You need to implement the interface, and then you register your event handler like this:

> graphdb.registerTransactionEventHandler(
>   myHandler );

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Can you create your own Rule function?

http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/guides/rules_and_functions.html#creating-your-own-rule-function

Comment: I read that but I couldn't really figure out how this worked. Is a "rule" the same as a trigger then?

Comment: No, but "rule function" seem to be it.